# Why is the data.length undefined in jqGrid loadComplete function?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have the code as follows:

```
    $(function () {                 
        jQuery("#list48").jqGrid({
            datatype: "xml",
            url: 'server.java',     
            mtype: "POST",
            colNames:['Inv No','Date'],
            colModel:[
                {name:'id',index:'id', width:60,},
                {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90}                  
            ],
            width: 600,             
            caption: "Grouping Array Data",
            loadComplete: function (data) {
                console.log("### data: " , data);  //Document
                console.log("### data.length: " , data.length);  //undefined
            }
        });
    })
```

After server response the table is contained by data. Everythig looks correct. 
Is there any any idea why the `data.length` is `undefined`?

Comment: What do you mean by "Document"? If `data` is the xml document you loaded (like the docs indicate), then it does of course not have a `.length` property. What did you expect it to be?

Comment: @Bergi, I wanted to change the icon for each item of the first level of TreeGrid as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480708/jqgrid-treegrid-custom-css-class-for-each-tree-level/9482049#9482049). The commenter loaded the data using json hense there is a lenght property in that case. And in my case the response type is xml, that's why there is no a length property. I got it. Very thanks! Please, "post your answer" in order I can check the post as soleved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're loading your data as an XML document (`datatype: "xml"`), and you are getting a [`Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document) back as seen in the log statement. Those don't have a `.length`, but collections of child nodes which you can iterate.