# Cell editing of the jqgrid - tree grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, treegrid

Is it possible to use cell editing in JQGrid - tree grid?
When I add editable option, it doesn't work

```
colModel: [
                    { name: 'fieldName', index: 'id',  width: 10, hidden:true},                     
                    { name: 'level', index: 'level',  width: 10, hidden:true},

{ name: 'field1', index: 'field2', width: 60, classes:'field2Section', align: 'right',
                **editable:true**, formatter:'number',
                formatoptions: { decimalSeparator: ".", thousandsSeparator: ",", decimalPlaces: 
                 2, 
                 defaultValue: '0.00' }
},
...
], //end of colModel
treeGrid: true,
treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
ExpandColumn : 'fieldName',
...
```

My tree grid, works OK, by itself.
In my JSON object, I have fields named "level" and "isLeaf".  Set accordingly to my specs.. some to true some to false.

I want to make reandom cells editable upon clicking on them.  Does jQgrid supports it?  For the moment, I just want to achieve a cell becoming editable, and then I will be taking care of what do do on afterEdit.. event.
Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose it's hard to do accordint for this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9976663/1849444) by @Oleg

Comment: Thanks, @teovankot, and thanks a lot to Oleg.
It worked out.

Comment: no problem. post your solution as answer and accept it. In case if some one else will try to do it.